# How to find biggest anagram in given paragraph in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am trying to find the biggest anagram in given paragraph. Assume a string is provided to me containing words. Now I want to find all the anagrams and among all anagrams I want to return a list of all the biggest anagrams.

For example,

```
String s = "Hello jjkkllmm how are you. See you at lljjmmkk tomorrow with kkjjmmll. ootty tyoto"
```

Here the words *jjkkllmm*, *lljjmmkk*, *kkjjmmll*, *ootty, and *tyoto* are anagrams, among them the words *jjkkllmm*, *lljjmmkk*, and *kkjjmmll* are biggest and equal in size, so my method should return all biggest and equally sized anagram words.

I tried the below code from my side, but I don't know if it is the perfect solution or if it can be improved.

```
public static Set<String> findAllAnagram(String words)
{
    Map<String,String> tempMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    Set<String> allAnagrams = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    String[] wordArr = words.split(" ");

    for (String string : wordArr)
    {
        if(tempMap.containsKey(sort(string)))
        {
            allAnagrams.add(tempMap.get(sort(string)));
            allAnagrams.add(string);
        }
        else
        {
            tempMap.put(sort(string), string);
        }
    }
    return allAnagrams;
}

public static String findBiggestAnagram(String word)
{
    Set<String> allAnagrams =findAllAnagram(word);
    int biggestAnnagramCount = 0;
    String biggestAnnaGramWord = "";
    for (String string : allAnagrams)
    {
        if(biggestAnnagramCount<string.length())
        {
            biggestAnnaGramWord = string;
            biggestAnnagramCount=string.length();
        }
    }
    return biggestAnnaGramWord;
}
```

Comment: Did you try something ? Are you just expecting us to write the code ?

Comment: I'm not good with java, but you could try to s.split(" ") (turn the string into an array), then loop through it and compare each word to each word, seeing if they are the same length, and have the same instance of each letter.

Comment: @dystroy I have added my research and tries.

Comment: @RaisAlam Good. Does this code work ? If so, what isn't good ? If you just need a review, you might ask http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dystroy this code works fine for me. I want other alternatives that's why I didn't posted my research and tries first which results in negative reputation.

Comment: OK. This isn't really the purpose of SO, that's why I gave you the link to codereview. You might simplify your code using my approach below (only one map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string by space and add each words into a set after sorting the string which return false after adding to set is actually anagram because it is already added.

```
   char[] chars = original.toCharArray();
   Arrays.sort(chars);
   String sorted = new String(chars);
   set.add(sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to build a key for each anagram.

An obvious one would be built by lowercasing and sorting the letters ("See" => "ees").

Using a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` to keep all versions of an anagram, you'd iterate over the words to link them to their key.

After that, you'd simply take the biggest key among the ones having more than one element in the list.